# How to add a project to Github dependents graph?

Tags: ruby, github, npm, rubygems

I've just seen that Github has released a new feature that show a list of depends project https://github.com/blog/2300-visualize-your-project-s-community.

[image: React depends list]

I see that in React depends list there are already some projects and I want to add my own project https://github.com/chrvadala/react-svg-pan-zoom to that list.

I have just created a `Gemfile` file that declare `react-source` as depends, but it doesn't works.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'react-source'
```

Are there any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You can install it locally via `gem install react-source` and call it. Or you can add this `gem 'react-source', '~> 0.13.3'` per the docs

Comment: I have changed as suggested, but I'm not listed yet https://github.com/facebook/react/network/dependents?type=application I don't know if I have to wait

Comment: If you're just looking to get your name on the list for github you might need to contact Facebook. They might only select certain dependents.